# How to remove row of CSV depending on column[0] name

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the [CSV](https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv) there is data from two sources. I want to separate them so only the data from GISTEMP is used. I thought of different things to put in the if statement but none of them worked. I'd prefer if the data from different sources was split up and stored individually so I could use GCAGyear, GCAGtemp and GISTEMPyear, GISTEMPtemp. But if that's not possible I'm fine with deleting all values from the source GCAG.

```
getTempData();

async function getTempData(){
    const response = await fetch('https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv')
    .then(response => response.text()); //goes to url and takes the text on page
    console.log(response)

    const table = response.split('\n').slice(1); //remove first line and splits raw text into array
    console.log(table)
    table.forEach(row => {
        const columns = row.split(','); 
        console.log(columns)
        if (columns[0] = 'GCAG'){


        }

        const year = columns[1];
        const temp = columns[2];
        //console.log(year, temp); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use filter function

```
      async function getTempData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv')
        .then(response => response.text());
    let table = response.split('\n').slice(1);
    table = table.map(item => item.split(','))
    const table_filterd = table.filter(item => item[0] && item[0].trim() === 'GISTEMP')
    table_filterd.forEach((row, index) => {
        const year = columns[1];
        const temp = columns[2];
        //console.log(year, temp); 
    });
}
```

Comment: After doing that I'm left with an empty array

Comment: I updated the answer I added .trim() function Please try it and tell me

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer I tried it locally and It works fine right now please check it again

Answer (score 0):

Made a function that returns all elements that include the names of the sources. Used filter to put them into their own arrays. Arrays created that store the source, year and mean. Elements are separated by commas.

```
getTempData();

async function getTempData(){
    const response = await fetch('https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv')
    .then(response => response.text()); //goes to url and takes the text on page

    const table = response.split('\n').slice(1); //remove first line and splits raw text into array
    function sourceGCAG(table){
        return (table.includes('GCAG'))
    }
    function sourceGISTEMP(table){
        return (table.includes('GISTEMP'))
    }
    tableGCAG = table.filter(sourceGCAG);
    tableGISTEMP = table.filter(sourceGISTEMP);

    tableGCAG.forEach(row => {
        const columns = row.split(',');
        const year = columns[1];
        const temp = columns[2];

        console.log(year, temp); 
    });

    tableGISTEMP.forEach(row => {
        const columns = row.split(',');
        const year = columns[1];
        const temp = columns[2];

        console.log(year, temp); 
    });
}
```